# Can I use two Kerberos Keytabs from a single host?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, kerberos

My application enables defining several LDAP servers to work with.
One might want to define Kerberos access to more than one LDAP server.
Can it be done? Can a single host juggle between Active Directory servers with Kerberos as the connection method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You just need to manage your keytabs yourself.

Basically just take the code from MIT Kerberos kinit and look how it creates the credentials cache and manages to load its keys. Just init the appropriate tickets before each connection and it should work.